I cant insert the korean into variation
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main() {
    char p[100];
    scanf("%s", p);
    printf("%s", p);
    return 0;
}

when I input Korean like "한" in the vscode, but there is something different like @ in the variation.


I don know What I have to change setting... plz help

I changed CRLF and UTF-8 but there is any different

Need more information. What is the execution code page?

Are you sure you don't want to be using wscanf, wprintf, etc.?

The most likely explanation is that you're using regular characters and functions designed to operate on them. If we use the variants provided in <wchar.h> you should see the correct behavior.
% cat test.c
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
    wchar_t test[100];
    wscanf(L"%s", test);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", test);
}
% gcc test.c
% ./a.out   
한
한

